# The alert dialog must not dismiss until user input text in editext is valid

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am making an alert dialog with edit text. I want that it will remain on screen until user input his email in it. How can I do that?? My code is as below:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setMessage("Enter Email:");
    final EditText userid = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(userid);
    userid.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (userid.getText().toString().length()>0){
                userId = userid.getText().toString();               
                result();
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your email for future reference.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

by clicking on any button the dialog dismisses. Please do tell how to retain the dailog on screen till i need it.Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this...

```
boolean flagEmail = false;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
            if (validate(email.getText().toString().trim())) 
            {
                flagEmail = true;
            }
```

Calling the Function of validate

```
public boolean validate(String emailId) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(emailId);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

In your Condition, if `flagEmail = true;` then let dialog button get cancel, else get a Toast message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setMessage("Enter Email:");
    final EditText userid = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(userid);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    userid.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (userid.getText().toString().length()>0){
                userId = userid.getText().toString();               
                result();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your email for future reference.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to set it so your dialog is not cancelable:

```
alert.setCancelable(false);
```

Then if the user presses the OK button without entering data you can do the following:

```
alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() { 
    public void onDismiss( DialogInterface dialog) { 
        //If userid get text not greater than 0
        //then reshow the alertdialog with alert.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This requires API 17.

Answer (score 1):

`alert.setCancelable(false);` and Use `TextUtils.isBlank(email)`

```
String email  = userid.getText().toString().trim();

if(!(TextUtils.isBlank(email))){//check here

}else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter your email for future reference.",                    
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```